# Not able to start Android Studio AVD at all

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My system specifications:

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz 2.00GHz
RAM: 8GB

I have also installed Intel HAXM and also enabled the virtualization technology in the BIOS settings.

I have tried creating Virtual Devices of all sorts of system images say Recommended, x86 and other images. But I have failed starting them. I get different sorts of error for different system images choosed.

Android Emulator closed unexpectedly

Message:

```
Operating system: Windows NT
                  6.1.7600 
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 61 stepping 4
     4 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXEC
Crash address: 0x7fed69cbb30
Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000
Process uptime: 0 seconds
```

[And this message also (sometimes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFILV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but I didn't get any perfect solution so, I installed genymotion plugin in android studio and later install the genymotion software and started using it as an emulator.
To install genymotion plugin go to file>settings>plugin>search for genymotion and intall it.
and for genymotion software google it.

Comment: Thanks rahul. But I have been using genymotion since I started coding android. I want to find potential solution for this problem and use AS's AVD. I have seen many systems that don't even meet requirements but still can run AVD.